# distinct list in entity framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, distinct

I search a lot but i can not find.
I want to use "**select distinct**" in entity framework.

my tables are:
scopes:`scopeID,ScopeName`
sports:`sportID,sportName`
Events:`eventID,scopeID,sportID`

```
public  List<Event> GetAllEvents(int sportID) 
{
   using (var mycontext= new MysiteEntities())
   {
      result= mycontext.Events   
                      .Where(l => l.SportID == sportID)
                      .OrderBy(l => l.ScopeID)
                      .ToList();
   }
   return result;
}
```

it return duplicate record by one scopeID.

events:

```
eventID scopeID sportID



  1        12      2
  2        12      2
  3        13      1
  4        13      2
  5        13      2
```

i want this result from:scopeID=12 and soprtID=2

```
 1        12      2
 3        13      2
```

how can do it?i want to return list from function.

thank you in advance.

Comment: oh,i am sorry.it was answer for my questions....